# Is there a .history file on Windows machines?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, powershell

Is there an auditable file on a Windows machine that shows the command-line history for either cmd or PowerShell? On UNIX machines I believe there is a hidden file in the home directory called .history.

Comment: Note that the hidden file _does not_ contain the _current_ history.  That's only in memory, as well.  This is why `history` has to be a built-in command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For plain old `cmd`, no there really isn't anything like that.

Even under PowerShell, I believe the history is still limited to the lifetime of the PowerShell session, though it [gives you the functionality](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176849.aspx) to work with and export the history, and even load it. You can use that to create some helper scripts to load and save your history easily as [demonstrated here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/01/perserving-command-history-across-sessions.aspx), but nothing out-of-the-box.

Comment: I believe the second paragraph is no longer accurate -- I don't *think* I've customized my powershell but it now retains history between launches.

Answer (score 4):

After looking into this some more it looks like there isn't a physical file-system file on Windows because everything is stored in memory. It looks like I can get the history using doskey.

```
doskey /history
```

I can extract a file by simply dumping that output to a file...

```
doskey /history > myhistoryfile.txt
```

Comment: That's only the history for the current console window's lifetime, as vcsjones says above.

Comment: Yep, but for regular-old "cmd" it looks like the only option. PowerShell isn't in use in this particular situation.